# Changing the Path of a file from a User's Input on a form in C#

Tags: c#

My user can create a file name that goes to a specific directory path(Textbox3) and they can change the directory path(TextBox4), I am having trouble reading Textbox4 which is the changing the path textbox.
It reads textbox3 just fine and does everything i need it to do if there is a filename in the textbox but when i put something in textbox4 it is not reading it.

```
    private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) //reads fine, file goes to C:\\Temp
    {
        string textBoxContents = textBox3.Text;
    }

    private void textBox4_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)//this is not required, this is only if they want to change where the file is going Ex:(D:\\Test
    {

        string textBoxContents = textBox4.Text;

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string Filename = textBox3.Text.Substring(0) + ".txt";
        string Filepath = textBox4.Text.Substring(0) + ".txt";
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\\Temp").Length;
        string path2 = Path.GetFullPath("C:\\Temp");
        string docPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
        string var = Path.Combine(docPath, path2);
        string var1 = Path.Combine(var, Filename);


        using (StreamWriter objWriter = new StreamWriter(var1))
        {
            int numpins = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            string basepin = textBox2.Text;
            int pinlength = basepin.Length;
            string formatspecifier = "{0:d" + pinlength.ToString() + "}" + "{1}";
            long pinnumber = long.Parse(basepin);
            string dig = textBox2.Text;
            string result = GetCheckDigit(dig);
            objWriter.WriteLine($"These are the Bin ranges");
            objWriter.WriteLine();

            for (int d = 0; d < numpins; d++)
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(dig))
                {
                    throw new Exception("null value not allowed");
                }
                else
                {
                    dig = pinnumber.ToString();
                    result = GetCheckDigit(dig);
                }

                basepin = string.Format(formatspecifier, pinnumber, result);
                objWriter.WriteLine(basepin);
                pinnumber++;
            }


            objWriter.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("File has been created");
        }

    }
```

Comment: I see several problems with the code presented in the question, but your specific question is not clear. You can "read:" textBox4 by accessing it's `Text` property. Please add more detail to the question about the specific problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: In the `TextChanged` events, you are creating a variable, assigning a value to it, and then it's not used and goes out of scope. What are you trying to do there? Should they be modifying a class field instead?

Comment: Ok the problem is that when I type a different path in textbox4.text the file that is created does not go to the specific path that i typed in textbox4.text, It continues to go in the path that is coded in (C:\\Temp)

Comment: Well, that's because there is no code there that uses the value of `textBox4.Text`. You only use the `Filename` variable, which is set to `textBox3.Text`.

Comment: So I would need another variable filename2 = textbox4.text for example?? Then StreamWriter would read it

Comment: You already have a variable for that called `Filepath` that's never used. You also capture the number of files in the directory in the `files` variable, which is also never used. The code is not very clear. What are you trying to do? Is the goal here that you always want to use whichever path the most recently changed?

Comment: Well it is a form that I created that creates a file with numbers in it and saves it to a directory, and basically the user can type in anything in textbox3 and it will attach (.txt) to it and will be found in C:\\Temp well in textbox4 the user can change the path of the file created and that is where i have my issue.

Comment: So textbox 3 is the file name and textbox 4 is the path? Sorry, but it's still not clear based on the code you've presented, because you're adding ".txt" to both those values, rather than trying to combine them into  a full path.

Comment: Yes but Textbox4 is not necessary so the code will run without it, ONLY if the user wants the file to save in a different folder or different drive that is when textbox4 comes into play.

Comment: so just set a variable for the path to a default directory, and change it if textbox4.text is a valid path, then use Path.Combine to combine the two into a full path+filename.

Comment: Ok and all of this can be done under the button1_Click or does it need to go under textbox4_textchanged

Comment: FYI, there's not need to call `Substring(0)`. That just returns the whole string.

Comment: Ok thank you so much

Comment: You were right I did not need (.txt) for  textbox4 because that is a file path not file name